# AWS SQS Lambda Trigger and Concurrency

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-sqs

I've seen a number of SO questions on limiting Lambda concurrent execution but none on the inverse issue.

I need to increase my concurrent execution but am having issues.  I've got a **Lambda triggered off an SQS** queue.  I've published a version of the function and **assigned it 3,000 concurrent execution** (my limit has been increased to 5,000 from the default of 1,000).

[image]

Despite this, when I run my process I see hundreds of thousands of messages waiting in the queue while the Monitoring tab of my Lambda function shows my **"Concurrent executions" never going above 1,250** and my "ProvisionedConcurrencyUtilization" never going above 50%.  Moreover, the chart seems to imply a hard limit of 1,250.

[image]

I'd be inclined to suspect that there is some sort of limit preventing any single Lambda from using more than 25% of total provisioned capacity (1,250 is 25% of 5,000) but the AWS documentation states otherwise.  I did see this SO question ([AWS Lambda Triggered by SQS increases SQS request count](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52904643/aws-lambda-triggered-by-sqs-increases-sqs-request-count)) which discusses Labmda/SQS polling but it and the documentation it links to indicate my process should use 100% of the Provisioned Capacity.  But perhaps it's the polling that's causing the issue.

In any event, these messages sit in the queue for over an hour to process ... with never more than 1,250 processing at the same time ... while the reset of that provisioned concurrency sits idle.

Any suggestions/ideas are greatly appreciated.

Comment: I would suggest opening a support ticket.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Jelly's suggestion was a good one.

Unfortunately, AWS says there is a hard limit of 1,250 Lambda concurrent executions when using Amazon SQS trigger.

Comment: Interesting! There's no mention of that in the documentation.